# How can replace commas with spaces on input tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a form with input tags! But i need replace the commas with spaces.

1.This is the HTML

```
<input id="tags_1" type="text" class="form-control tags" value="foo,bar,baz,roffle" name="formula">
```

2.And this is my script

```
var handleTagsInput = function () {
    if (!jQuery().tagsInput) {
        return;
    }
    $('#tags_1').tagsInput({
        width: 'auto',
        'onAddTag': function () {
            //alert(1);
        },
    });
```

Comment: What is `tagsInput`, is that a jQuery plugin? Can you add a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all the commas with spaces in `str`:

```
str = str.replace(/,/g, ' ');
```

If you want to change the value of an input, you can do:

```
$("#tags_1").val(function(i, oldval) {
    return oldval.replace(/,/g, ' ');
});
```

More complete:

```
$("#formid").submit(function() {
    $("#tags_1").val(function(i, oldval) {
        return oldval.replace(/,/g, ' ');
    });
});
```

This will replace all the commas when the user submits the form.

Comment: Barmar where need to put that?

Comment: Wherever you want to change the string.

Comment: I don't know anything about the `tagsInput` plugin you're using. My answer is for ordinary jQuery form processing.

Comment: ok i remove my plugin if you show me an example tag input in jsfiddle Bar

Comment: See my latest update showing how to do it when the form is submitted. This isn't rocket science, you just decide what you want to trigger the replacement, and put my code in there. Do you really need every little bit spelled out for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "foo,bar,baz,roffle"
a.split(",").join(" ")
```